# Can't derive Eq nor Show for newtype

Tags: haskell

I am having trouble deriving Eq and Show for the newtype.

```
newtype Comp a = Comp {unComp :: a -> a } deriving (Eq, Show)
```

When I try to load this file into my stack ghci, it tells me "No instance for (Show (a -> a))"

But the exact same definition loads fine in another file. Actually the previous file was having issues too but then it just stopped for some odd reason.

Comment: Relevant: https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/11008

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A `newtype`/`data` declaration cannot derive `Show` or `Eq` unless the types it is containing have instances for them.

By default, function types don't have instances for either `Show` or `Eq`, because there is very little useful information those could use, without having arguments to pass in.

However, it is possible to give them dummy instances, and some modules do so. The reason your declaration works in the other file is almost certainly that it is importing some module that exports (directly or indirectly) such instances.

Comment: Based on previous questions, I would guess specifically the instance from `Data.Universe.Instances.Reverse`. It is by no means your standard dummy instance -- it satisfies `read . show = id` -- but the remainder of your analysis sounds right to me.

Comment: So my only choice is to derive Data.Universe.Instances.Reverse again? Is there a way to satisfy the compiler without language extensions or third party packages? I will use a language extension if I have to though. I want to keep my examples independent of these things as much as possible, while I try to learn the basics of Haskell.

Comment: @mac10688 Well if you want equality for functions to be a genuine equality, and `read . show` to be `id`, then you really need something like `Finite` from that library, because the instances actually *have* to evaluate the functions at all possible values - Haskell functions are opaque and that's the only way to get the information out of them.

Comment: So I guess the trick is to have the function produce a type that derives Show and evaluate it with unComp. I'm still fuzzy about all of this, which is why I was holding off on marking this as the answer, but oh well. Maybe it'll sink in later.